# Parsing error: Unexpected token React in functional component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning React and getting an error while displaying values from props in a functional component. I know the syntax is wrong but don't know how to fix it.
When the same functional component was written as a class component it was working fine.But in functional component its giving syntax error. 
Code:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Crypto from './Component/Crypto';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        data: [
            {
                name:'Bitcoin',
                id:1,
                value:'2000'
            },
            {
                name:'Ripple',
                id:2,
                value:'60'
            },
            {
                name:'Etherium',
                id:3,
                value:'250'
            }
        ]
    }
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Crypto data={this.state.data}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Crypto.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Crypto=(props)=> {

    return (
        <div className="App">
      {const showData=props.data.map((info)=>
          return (
            <div key={info.id}>
            <h3>{info.name}</h3>
            <h2>${info.value}</h2>
            </div>
          )
      )}
        {showData}
      </div>
    );
  }


export default Crypto;
```

error:  `{const showData=props.data.map((info)=>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
return (
        <div className="App">
      {const showData=props.data.map((info)=> //<==== remove const showData
          return (
            <div key={info.id}>
            <h3>{info.name}</h3>
            <h2>${info.value}</h2>
            </div>
          )
      )}
        {showData}                      //<==== remove {showData}
      </div>
    );
```

```js
return (
        <div className="App">
      {props.data.map((info)=>
          return (
            <div key={info.id}>
            <h3>{info.name}</h3>
            <h2>${info.value}</h2>
            </div>
          )
      )}
      </div>
    );
```

The problem I noticed is you declare the variable in your `return` statement. You should instead remove it `showData` and using solely `map` function to return the desired output

Comment: So if I store the map array values inside a variable and try to display it inside a functional component is it not going to work?

Comment: @user11066242: I don't understand because `props.data` is already a list, why would you want to store it into another variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
const Crypto = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="row">
                {props.data.map((info) => (
                <ul className="list-group">  // if you are using map better to use index
                    <h3>Name {info.name}</h3>
                    <li className="list-group-item">Value: {info.value}</li>
                </ul>
                ))}

        </div>
    )
};

export default Crypto;
```

Comment: I dont think using `index` as key is a good practice. Using `id` is definitely a better option instead

Comment: Its not about index or id. Its about using unique value. In every iteration we get index value unique. This is what I think. Anyway as you said it depends upon practice. Your call.

Comment: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318 Not really my call or what not but there has been numerous articles about its bad to use index as key. Of course you're right, whether to follow or not, your call

Comment: Hello @Isaac Thanks for the info. Agreed.